# How to set the contentview of an activity using a button of another activity

Tags: android

I have a button on the main activity that when clicked runs a method. In the method I have an intent to a second activity, but i want to set the content view of that activity with the button from the first activity because i want to have more than one button on the first activity, but reuse the second activity and just change the layout. So....

Click button1 > sets view to layout1 > starts activity with layout1 as the contentview
OR
Click button2 > sets view to layout2 > starts activity with layout2 as the contentview

I would like to do it this way to avoid creating too many activities

Thanks

Comment: why don't use start another activity on button click.

Comment: There are different ways to do it but any of them are probably going to make it more confusing. Depending on what they do, you may have to keep track of what variables belong to what `layouts`

Comment: Im not sure about your question, but I think you have to see in side of fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add extra info to your intent using Intent.putExtra(String key, int data). Then in the second activity use getIntent().getIntExtra(key). You can use something other than an integer for your data but I recommend it so you can easily use a switch block.

EDIT:

Also, as yarian said:

> You can just pass the layout itself, it's just an int that sits in the R file.

It is probably a good idea to do this to eliminate the switch block (unless you need to execute other code as well, but this is still a good idea as you won't be defining separate constants for each layout to pass) So in your first activity say:

```
intent.putExtra("LAYOUT", R.layout.layout_name);
```

And in the second:

```
setContentView(getIntent().getIntExtra("LAYOUT"), DEFAULTVALUE);
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: You don't need to call getExtras. Just call `getIntent().getStringExtra(key)` or `getIntExtra(key)` or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Not that the other answers weren't helpful, this one gave an examples, which i think help people to learn better

Comment: the getIntExtra throws an error saying i need to add an extra int.
it wants ....getIntExtra("LAYOUT", <int here>));

Comment: Oh, yeah. you need a default value that it returns if it couldn't find your key. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

there are many ways to do it. here are just a few of them:

1. pass the argument of which layout to use by adding extra int to the intent (putExtra) and on the onCreate of the second activity use the intent to get it.
2. use fragments instead of activities , there you would have even more ways to do it.
3. not recommended - using a static int.

Answer (score 1):

When either of the buttons is clicked you start the second activity through an intent, in which you put value 1 if the first button is clicked, value 2 if the second one is clicked.

Then in the second activity you read a value from an Intent and if it's 1 you setContentView to be the first layout, if it's 2 to be the second layout.

Comment: You can just pass the layout itself, it's just an int that sits in the R file.